# is there a way of passing the cars component as the search result from the search inputs in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This is the code for my search component, it contains the search input that returns a search result

```
function Search (props) {
const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
 function handleSearch(e){
   setSearch(e.target.value)
 };
      const filtered = !search
    ? data
    : data.filter((car) =>
        car.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
    
  return(
    <>
    <div className="search-container">
    <input 
    value={search}
    onChange={handleSearch}
    className="searchbox"
    type='text'
    placeholder="Find a car.."/>
    </div>     
    </>  
  )
}
```

this is my CARS COMPONENT it shows the the collective lists of cars from my data

```
function Cars (){
    
  return(
    <> 
   
    <div className="cars-container">
     {data.map((car) =>{
      return (
       <div className="cars-wrapper"
           key={car.number}>         
          <img className='car-image' 
          src={car.image} alt="mercedez" />
          <h4>{car.name}</h4>
          <p>{car.model}</p> 
        <Link style={{fontSize: '1rem'}}
        to={`/cars/${car.number}`}>Mind blowing features</Link> 
       </div>
      )
     })}
   
      </div> 
   <Outlet />       
   </>
  )
    }


     export {Cars}
```

Now my question is, how can i pass the CARS component to the SEARCH component to be displayed whenever the search input is used to search for a car.

Comment: what is the difference between Cars data and Search data?

Comment: Do you need the Search component to be used in for searching for car usecase and another usecase?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are several ways to do this.

1. You can create a parent element in which you declare a state, for example filtered, which you will pass to searchComponent where it will change, and in carComponent you will pass the already filtered state:

Like this:

```js
 const Parent () => {
   const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState('');
   const handleFilter = (data) => {
          setFiltered(data)
   }
        
   return (<>
     <Search setFiltered={handleFilter}/>
     <Cars data={filtered}/>
   </>)
}
```

2. You can create custom hooks with state, put them in a separate file, and use their state where you want, although I'm not entirely sure about this approach, because. I myself have been using more advanced methods for a long time.

That's about custom hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

3. Use libraries for state management like [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/README.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)